# Set Shared Preference Volley StringRequest

Tags: android, android-volley, android-sharedpreferences

I am using Volley to make an HTTP Post request.

This is working fine, however within the onResponse method I am trying to set a SharedPreference value, this value does not seem to be being set however.

The Volley code:

```
public void sendPostRequest() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progress.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (obj.has("success")){

                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = LoginActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
                        editor.commit();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        error.setText(obj.getString("error"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                System.out.println("volley Error .................");
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("username", emailTxt.getText().toString());
                params.put("password", passwordTxt.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

The Intent gets fired so I know we are hitting the success if statement.

The below code is run in the launcher activity to by pass login if the user has already logged in

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean loggedIn = sharedPref.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);

                if (loggedIn){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

    }
```

However loggedIn is always false.

Comment: Is this code in splash screen?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes the bottom code is a spash screen

Comment: Then u should call this function before load your views. Log this _loggedIn _ in splash screen what is the value for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As see here:

[getPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int))

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity

Both `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity` Activity is different, so getting always `false`.

Use `getSharedPreferences` instead of `getPreferences` in both Activities to get it work.